# Can we split the window in to 3 parts in android

Tags: android-source, display, multi-window, split-screen

In android 7.1.2 we can split the window in to 2 parts.

Like that, can we split the window in to 3 parts (AOSP)?

I have followed this link https://source.android.com/devices/tech/display/multi-window

Comment: The page you linked clearly lists the current implementations: split-screen (which "provides two activity panes"), freeform (floating panels), and picture-in-picture.

Comment: yes,Now my requirement to split in to 3 parts and trying modify the code in framework level.I am going correct way ?

Comment: So, you're trying to build a customised version of Android which shows 3 apps on the screen in resizable panels? If so, what is your question exactly? Are you looking for a link to someone else who's made a similar modification?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply . yes,Exactly. I thought to know i am going correct way

Comment: OK. I'm still not sure what you're asking though. To put it a different way, what information would you expect someone to give in an answer? Bear in mind that this is not a discussion site, so open-ended questions are discouraged. Have a read of the [help] and take the [tour] if you haven't already.

Comment: I got solution,Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution,
Just have to run command using adb.

adb shell settings put global enable_freeform_support 1

Comment: How to split 3 parts?